# Using data.table's fread with varying lengths for blank missing values

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with many missing values.  Some of the missing values are NAs, some are Nulls, and others have varying lengths of blank spaces.  I would like to utilize the `fread` function in `R` to be able to read all these values as missing.

Here is an example:

```
#Find fake data
iris <- data.table(iris)[1:5]

#Add missing values non-uniformly
iris[1,Species:='         ']
iris[2,Species:=' ']
iris[3,Species:='NULL']

#Write to csv and read back in using fread
write.csv(iris,file="iris.csv")
fread("iris.csv",na.strings=c("NULL"," "))

   V1 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1:  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2          
2:  2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2        NA
3:  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2        NA
4:  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
5:  5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
```

From the above example, we see that I am unable to account for the first missing value since there are many blank spaces.  Any one know of a way to account for this?

Comment: either add all possible lengths of spaces or set it to `NA` *after* reading it in?

Comment: I am currently using ```mclapply(data,function(x) ifelse(str_trim(x)=='',NA,toupper(str_trim(x))),mc.cores=10)``` to convert everything, but it isn't super-fast.  I guess there could be a way for me to take into account all possible spaces using ```paste``` and ```rep```

Comment: It is on Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: try `fread("sed 's/ *//g' yourfile")` or some variation of the regex, depending on what exactly your data looks like

Comment: That seems to work for my test case (the iris dataset) above in the terminal, but I can't seem to get it to work using ```fread```

Comment: you have to be more specific

Comment: sorry...I get following error when I use that code ```fread("sed 's/ *//g' iris.csv")
#Error in fread("sed 's/ *//g' iris.csv") : 
#  file not found: sed 's/ *//g' iris.csv```.  If I use ```sed 's/ *//g' iris.csv``` in the terminal alone, it prints out a dataset with no spaces in the missing cells

Comment: perhaps your `data.table` version is pre 1.8.9 (iirc that's when `fread` started supporting the above syntax)?

Comment: My ```sessionInfo``` says ```data.table_1.8.10```.  This is perplexing.

Comment: Maybe it was 1.8.11 then - just upgrade to at least 1.9.2 and try again please

Comment: It works! At least it works on my home network.  Now I just need to get our server administrators to allow us to upgrade ```data.table``` versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks so much for the wonderful answer from @eddi.

```
fread("sed 's/ *//g' iris.csv",na.strings=c("",NA,"NULL"))
```